# Applying style for title of span tag

Tags: html, css

My requirement is to apply style on the title attribute of the span tag. I tried so many ways and it did not work

```
<span title="Hello" class="span_style"> hello </span>
```

I want to change the back ground color if user hovers on the text.

if i hover on the text i will be getting some information about it (tool tip). for that tool tip i want the back ground to be changed from the default

I wrote like this

```
.span_style title: hover {
   background-color: rgba(81, 85, 89, 0.8);
}
```

It did not work.

Comment: span[title] ... what do you mean title attribute style

Comment: if we hover on the text some text will be shown and i need a specific background for that text

Comment: @hema Luna it is not duplicate of that. I have checked that before posting it did not work

Comment: It was. Based on your question. You want to change the background color of the span title. Maybe, what you mean is change the span background color which has the title of "Hello".

Comment: Be more specified, what you exactly want to do.

Answer (score 0):

It will never work, what you need is boostrap tooltip or popover plugin. Very simple to install and use.

Read about Bootstrap Tooltip here
https://getbootstrap.com/javascript#tooltips

Or

http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_tooltip.asp

Comment: you wrong, its can work with css only. check my answer.